# jQuery 1.6.2 Line 8493 IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-easing

**Update: RESOLVED.**

Hio,

So I can't figure out why this error is ocurring in IE8 *ONLY*, on http://www.vulytrampolines.com/store. We think it has something to do with the countdown timer.

> Object doesn't support this property or method  jquery.js, line 8493
>   character 5

This is line 8493:

```
this.pos = jQuery.easing[ options.animatedProperties[ this.prop ] ]( this.state, n, 0, 1, options.duration );
```

Anyone have any idea? We use the easing library, included after loading of jQuery, but it should still work while loading the jQuery library.

Comment: It's likely that some other part does not run as expected, and failed the expectation of this line.  If you show your code or some independent simplified code that, when called, would cause this error, then we may be able to find the cause faster. jsfiddle is a good start.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/benno_007/5MWHJ/1/ thing is - it works fine in jsFiddle. When I remove the #counter div from the html on my website, I DON'T get the error. So... confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was something to do with rgba styles and an image that faded in using .animate with an easing option.